# Select all Roles Except Administrator. C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a controller action that I have to change/Add roles in the admin section. I have used this same code in the users section for use of a Company Admin to be able to change/Add roles for their company users. The problem is it produces a list of all the roles they are not in, including Admin. Which obviously I do not want. I am looking for a way to put a where clause in this statement.

```
var colAllRoles = RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Below is the whole Action, maybe there is a better place in the action to do this? However I tried putting a where clause in this and it didn't like it. It seems that the Select cannot be used if the Where is used and without the Select it doesn't work at all.

Thanks for your help!

```
private List<string> RolesUserIsNotIn(string UserName)
{
        // Get roles the user is not in
        var colAllRoles = RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        // Go get the roles for an individual
        Models.ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(UserName);

        // If we could not find the user, throw an exception
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find the User");
        }

        var colRolesForUser = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id).ToList();
        var colRolesUserInNotIn = (from objRole in colAllRoles
                                   where !colRolesForUser.Contains(objRole)
                                   select objRole).ToList();

        if (colRolesUserInNotIn.Count() == 0)
        {
            colRolesUserInNotIn.Add("No Roles Found");
        }

        return colRolesUserInNotIn;
}
```

EDIT

I have added my Private UserAndRoles GetUserAndRoles. This is where the list is populated. I have taken the advice to keep it out of the RolesUserIsIn and modified the code below so that it populates the list without the Admin.

Line of code that was changed:

```
 ViewBag.AddRole = new SelectList(RolesUserIsIn(UserName));
```

This is the whole code sample with the changes:

```
    private UserAndRolesDTO GetUserAndRoles(string UserName)
    {
        // Go get the User
        Models.ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(UserName);

        List<UserRoleDTO> colUserRoleDTO =
            (from objRole in UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id)
             select new UserRoleDTO
             {
                 RoleName = objRole,
                 UserName = UserName
             }).ToList();

        if (colUserRoleDTO.Count() == 0)
        {
            colUserRoleDTO.Add(new UserRoleDTO { RoleName = "No Roles Found" });
        }

        var roleList = RolesUserIsNotIn(UserName);
        var roleListWithoutAdmin = roleList.Where(f => f != "Administrator");
        ViewBag.AddRole = new SelectList(roleListWithoutAdmin);

        // Create UserRolesAndPermissionsDTO
        UserAndRolesDTO objUserAndRolesDTO =
            new UserAndRolesDTO
            {
                UserName = UserName,
                ColUserRoleDTO = colUserRoleDTO
            };
        return objUserAndRolesDTO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a where condition to exclude the `Admin` role item from the list of roles.

I would not do it inside the `RolesUserIsNotIn` method. I would do it outside of the method so that this method does only one thing, getting roles which the user is not in.

First call your method which gets a list of roles which the user is not in. Then call `Where` method on that to exlcude a specific item.

```
var roleList = RolesUserIsNotIn("SomeuserName");
//Not exclude Admin
var roleListWithoutAdmin = roleList.Where(f=>f!="Admin");
```

The variable `roleListWithoutAdmin` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a list, you can call the `ToList()` method on that or the LINQ expression.

Comment: So implement this maybe in the GetUsersAndRoles which is Private modifying this line? ViewBag.AddRole = new SelectList(RolesUserIsNotIn(UserName));

Comment: Your question did not have any line using the expression `ViewBag.AddRole`. So I am not sure about that.

Comment: You are free to use the `Where` method anywhere as you feel appropriate in the LINQ expression  (on a collection of strings). Like I said, my personal opinion is to do it outside of the `RolesUserNotIn` method so that that method does only one thing as the name suggests

Comment: Glad to know! If you are already using a view model to transfer data between your action method and view, I suggest adding a property to that to transfer the SelectListItems instead of using ViewBag.My personal choice is to avoid ViewBag 90% of the time.

Comment: Yes, I hate viewbag as well. Right now it is the only spot in my entire project that is using it. Have to do some cleanup! thanks.